# Counter +1 action for game in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to code the `ctr` as counter + 1 when user select action three, to count one out of 40 for restriction numbers. I couldn't figure it out because I keep getting the same error 5 different times. I am new to Python this year. Any have an idea?

This is called Monster game I wanted to build for part of my project at the university. I have not figured it out yet.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = 40
        self.atk = 5
        self.sp = 10
        self.snk = 3 #FOR SNACKS ONLY
        self.lvl = 1
        self.exp = 0
    def attack(self, other):
        print("%s attacks %s for %d damage\n"%(self.name, other.name, self.a>
        other.takeDamage(self.atk, self)
    def takeDamage(self, dmg):
        print("%s takes %d damage\n" % (self.name, dmg))
        self.hp -= dmg
        #if(self.hp <= 0):
        #    self.die()
    #def die(self):
        #print("%s died" %(self.name))
        #print("-------GAMEOVER-------")
        #print("You earned %d exp this game" %(self.exp))
    def takeTurn(self, monsterArray):
        print("%s HP:%d"%(self.name, self.hp))
        print("Atk:%d"%(self.atk))
        print("SP:%d"%(self.sp))
        print()
        #For every monster i, print information about it
        for i in monsterArray:
            #print information about Monster i
            i.printInfo()
        action = self.getAction()
        #Player selected "Attack"
        if(action == 1):
            print("\nChoose target: ")
            counter = 0
            for i in monsterArray:
                print("\n%d: " % (counter), end="")
                i.printInfo()
                counter += 1
            userInput = int(input(">"))

            self.attack(monsterArray[userInput])
            if(monsterArray[userInput].hp <= 0):
                monsterArray.pop(userInput)
        if(action == 2):
            print("\nYou are in Passive mode... - 1 dmg!\n")
            self.hp -= 1
        if(action == 3):
            print("\nYou are heal up to 3+ SP")
            self.hp +=  8
            ctr = ctr + 1 #count how many time used

    def getAction(self):
        while(1):
            print("\nAvailable actions:")
            print("1: Attack")
            print("2: Passive Mode [-1 dmg]")
            print("3: Snacks [%d out of 40]" % (ctr), end="")
            try:
                userInput = int(input(">"))
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter a number")
                continue
            if(userInput < 1 or userInput > 3):
                print("invalid action number")
                continue
            elif(userInput == 2 and self.sp < 5):
                print("Loser! \n You are skipping yourself. Continue to figh>
                continue
            elif(userInput == 3 and self.hp< 40):
                print("NO MORE.... Use your health leftover!")
                continue
            return userInput
```

EXPECTED:

```
cs15125@cs:/u1/class/cs15125/project> python3 battle.py
Enter your name adventurer:
> EXAMPLE
EXAMPLE HP:40
Atk:5
SP:10

Diggle - HP:10
Tegmul - HP:5
Erthran - HP:7
Ozal - HP:14
Xag'thazok - HP:10

Available actions:
1: Attack
2: Passive Mode [-1 dmg]
3: Snack [5 out of 40]

> 3
```

ACTUAL:

```
Enter your name adventurer:
> EXAMPLE
EXAMPLE HP:40
Atk:5
SP:10

Diggle - HP:10
Tegmul - HP:5
Erthran - HP:7
Ozal - HP:14
Xag'thazok - HP:10

Available actions:
1: Attack
2: Passive Mode [-1 dmg]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "battle.py", line 19, in <module>
    p.takeTurn(monArray) #done
  File "/u1/class/cs15125/project/player.py", line 31, in takeTurn
    action = self.getAction()
  File "/u1/class/cs15125/project/player.py", line 60, in getAction
    print("3: Snacks [%d out of 40]" % (ctr), end="")
NameError: name 'ctr' is not defined
cs15125@cs:/u1/class/cs15125/project>
```

This is the second file in my directory to run Battle.py

battle.py:

```
from monster import *
from player import Player

red = "\u001b[31m"
green = "\u001b[32m"
yellow = "\u001b[33m"
blue = "\u001b[34m"
cyan = "\u001b[36m"
#white = ""
reset = "\u001b[0m"

u = input(blue + "Enter your name adventurer:\n> " + reset)
p = Player(u)

monArray = createMonsters()
#print(monArray[0].name)

while(1):
  p.takeTurn(monArray) #done

  #for every monster
  #      monster take turn
  for i in monArray:
    i.takeTurn(p)

  if(p.hp <= 0):
    print("YOU'RE DEAD! Best of luck next time!")
    exit()
  if(len(monArray) == 0):
    #game ends, you win
    print("You WON!")
    exit()
```

monster.py

```
class Monster:
    def __init__(self, name, hp, atk):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.atk = atk
        self.exp = (hp/10)+atk
    def takeDamage(self, dmg, other):
        print("The %s takes %d damage" % (self.name, dmg))
        self.hp -= dmg
        if(self.hp <= 0):
            self.die(other)
    def die(self, other):
        print("The %s dies in a pool of disappointment" %(self.name))
        other.exp += self.exp
        print("%s gains %d exp" %(other.name,self.exp))
    def printInfo(self):
        print("%s - HP:%d" % (self.name, self.hp))
    def takeTurn(self, player):
        self.attack(player)
    def attack(self, other):
        print("%s attacks %s for %d damage"%(self.name, other.name, self.atk))
        other.takeDamage(self.atk)



#Loads data.txt, reading monster information.
#Parsing the text into monster objects.
#Appended obj to array, returning the array.
def createMonsters():
    monArray = []
    try:
        f = open("data.txt","r")
    except:
        print("Can't open data.txt")
        exit()
    fileData = f.read().split("\n")
    f.close()
    i = 0
    while(i < len(fileData)):
        dataLine = fileData[i].split(":")
    if(dataLine[0] == "Name"):
        name = dataLine[1]
        dataLine = fileData[i+1].split(":")
        hp = int(dataLine[1])
        dataLine = fileData[i+2].split(":")
        atk = int(dataLine[1])
        m = Monster(name, hp, atk)
        monArray.append(m)
    i += 1


return monArray
```

Comment: Can you show how battle.py looks like @Dev ?

Comment: How can I upload another battle.py?

Comment: Just edit your question to add the contents of that file @Dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the scope of `ctr`

You can do is:

define ctr globally:

`ctr = 0` # or whatever the value you would like

Then declare inside the function you want to reuse:

`global ctr`

And then you can use that inside any function without any error.

Hence your code for e.g.:

```
ctr = 0
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = 40
        self.atk = 5
        self.sp = 10
        self.snk = 3 #FOR SNACKS ONLY
        self.lvl = 1
        self.exp = 0
    def attack(self, other):
        print("%s attacks %s for %d damage\n"%(self.name, other.name, self.a>
        other.takeDamage(self.atk, self)
    def takeDamage(self, dmg):
        print("%s takes %d damage\n" % (self.name, dmg))
        self.hp -= dmg
        #if(self.hp <= 0):
        #    self.die()
    #def die(self):
        #print("%s died" %(self.name))
        #print("-------GAMEOVER-------")
        #print("You earned %d exp this game" %(self.exp))
    def takeTurn(self, monsterArray):
        global ctr # <---- here
        print("%s HP:%d"%(self.name, self.hp))
        print("Atk:%d"%(self.atk))
        print("SP:%d"%(self.sp))
        print()
        #For every monster i, print information about it
        for i in monsterArray:
            #print information about Monster i
            i.printInfo()
        action = self.getAction()
        #Player selected "Attack"
        if(action == 1):
            print("\nChoose target: ")
            counter = 0
            for i in monsterArray:
                print("\n%d: " % (counter), end="")
                i.printInfo()
                counter += 1
            userInput = int(input(">"))

            self.attack(monsterArray[userInput])
            if(monsterArray[userInput].hp <= 0):
                monsterArray.pop(userInput)
        if(action == 2):
            print("\nYou are in Passive mode... - 1 dmg!\n")
            self.hp -= 1
        if(action == 3):
            print("\nYou are heal up to 3+ SP")
            self.hp +=  8
            ctr = ctr + 1 #count how many time used

    def getAction(self):
        global ctr # <---- and here
        while(1):
            print("\nAvailable actions:")
            print("1: Attack")
            print("2: Passive Mode [-1 dmg]")
            print("3: Snacks [%d out of 40]" % (ctr), end="")
            try:
                userInput = int(input(">"))
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter a number")
                continue
            if(userInput < 1 or userInput > 3):
                print("invalid action number")
                continue
            elif(userInput == 2 and self.sp < 5):
                print("Loser! \n You are skipping yourself. Continue to figh>
                continue
            elif(userInput == 3 and self.hp< 40):
                print("NO MORE.... Use your health leftover!")
                continue
            return userInput
```

Without `global`:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = 40
        self.atk = 5
        self.sp = 10
        self.snk = 3 #FOR SNACKS ONLY
        self.lvl = 1
        self.exp = 0
        self.ctr = 0
    def attack(self, other):
        print("%s attacks %s for %d damage\n"%(self.name, other.name, self.a))
        other.takeDamage(self.atk, self)
    def takeDamage(self, dmg):
        print("%s takes %d damage\n" % (self.name, dmg))
        self.hp -= dmg
        #if(self.hp <= 0):
        #    self.die()
    #def die(self):
        #print("%s died" %(self.name))
        #print("-------GAMEOVER-------")
        #print("You earned %d exp this game" %(self.exp))
    def takeTurn(self, monsterArray):
        print("%s HP:%d"%(self.name, self.hp))
        print("Atk:%d"%(self.atk))
        print("SP:%d"%(self.sp))
        print()
        #For every monster i, print information about it
        for i in monsterArray:
            #print information about Monster i
            i.printInfo()
        action = self.getAction()
        #Player selected "Attack"
        if(action == 1):
            print("\nChoose target: ")
            counter = 0
            for i in monsterArray:
                print("\n%d: " % (counter), end="")
                i.printInfo()
                counter += 1
            userInput = int(input(">"))

            self.attack(monsterArray[userInput])
            if(monsterArray[userInput].hp <= 0):
                monsterArray.pop(userInput)
        if(action == 2):
            print("\nYou are in Passive mode... - 1 dmg!\n")
            self.hp -= 1
        if(action == 3):
            print("\nYou are heal up to 3+ SP")
            self.hp +=  8
            self.ctr = self.ctr + 1 #count how many time used

    def getAction(self):
        while(1):
            print("\nAvailable actions:")
            print("1: Attack")
            print("2: Passive Mode [-1 dmg]")
            print("3: Snacks [%d out of 40]" % (self.ctr), end="")
            try:
                userInput = int(input(">"))
            except ValueError:
                print("Please enter a number")
                continue
            if(userInput < 1 or userInput > 3):
                print("invalid action number")
                continue
            elif(userInput == 2 and self.sp < 5):
                print("Loser! \n You are skipping yourself. Continue to figh")
                continue
            elif(userInput == 3 and self.hp< 40):
                print("NO MORE.... Use your health leftover!")
                continue
            return userInput
```

Comment: It has to be up to 40, but it is over more than 40? Any suggestion?

Comment: I gave you answered but how do I up to only 40 restricted?

Comment: Can you edit the question and put how are you running your code? Is there any other code involved?

Comment: Not sure what you mean?

Comment: I mean how r u running your game? What inputs are you providing?

Comment: I run `python3 battle.py` to run but I also choose three and it count up to 40, but it also go over 41 out of 40. `if(action == 3):
            print("\nYou are heal up to 3+ SP")
            self.hp +=  8
            ctr = ctr + 1 #count how many time used`

Comment: can you upload `battle.py` file?

Comment: I did, in the bottom

Comment: What does monster file have? Actually all of the file depends upon each other.

Comment: You actually do not need global for this @Dev , and actually global is overkill gere. We can solve this in a much better fashion, can you add your `createMonsters` code to the question as well

Comment: Just added.... @DeveshKumarSingh -- I'm sorry but I don't understand?? Please explain showing more example?

Comment: I added the solution without global.

Comment: Looks much better @Ruturaj :) Using self is much better than global!